# UIDatePicker width issue IOS

Tags: ios, ipad

I have added a datePicker to the contentView of my custom tableViewCell in the **datePickerModeTime**. However, the minutes component is missing in the simulator once I run my application. I have tried the same with and without using Autolayout.

I have also tried changing the **height** to 216.0 and 162.0 but in vain.
Following is how I get the datePicker in the simulator without minutes.

[image]

Comment: Youl'd need to write your own customized picker in case you want minute component

Comment: Please be specific about your problem

Answer (score 0):

I have further tried solving this by setting the frame manually, even this did not work. I suppose that this is an issue with the **simulator** because I got it right when tried in **Ipad Air**.